# Exception in pyfingerprint python library using r305 sensor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, fingerprint

I followed the steps given in this [link](https://sicherheitskritisch.de/2015/03/fingerprint-sensor-fuer-den-raspberry-pi-und-debian-linux-en/)  . But i'm getting the following error:

```
The fingerprint sensor could not be initialized!
Exception message: The received packet do not begin with a valid header!
```

I tried changing the tx/rx wires but no use. The same error occurs.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually R305 works by some instructions in a specific format. The instructions are hex values, it includes header, packet command, checksum etc. 
Go through the following data sheet

http://www.rhydolabz.com/wiki/?p=15770

and Also you can use the following library

http://www.github.com/mohanbe/pyR305